# How to remove APIv4 extension

Tags: extension, apiv4

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find it if so. How can I remove the obsolete APIv4 extension cleanly? There's no disable or uninstall uption on the Extensions page. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you just delete the folder (or move it far away - completely out of the site)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would delete the extension folder from the extension directory.

You may need to run the below query to delete the entry from the extension table or sometimes it should delete automatically when you will hit refresh button on extension page

```
DELETE FROM civicrm_extension WHERE full_name = 'org.civicrm.api4';
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Deleted the folder, and then deleted the record from the extension table. Refresh wasn't enough.