# How can I remove obsolete extensions?

Tags: extension, delete

Both Afform and Api v4 are indicated as obsolete extensions, but there is no "uninstall" button.

[How to remove APIv4 extension](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42014/how-to-remove-apiv4-extension) seems to indicate that you should manually delete the extension directory and remove the entry from the database.

Is there no other, perhaps more, "safe" way to remove extensions?

Or should we just write that down to bad practice on the part of the extension developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, that's the only way to do it, Or should have uninstalled the extension prior to CiviCRM upgrade

Comment: Are you saying that as long as it is not "obsolete" we can delete it using the "uninstall" button?

Comment: Yes, uninstalling afform may lose all the forms you have created. But not incase of API4